# How to apply the same props to multiple styled components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I'm using the `styled-components` library to extend the header components from the `Blueprintjs` library. The `H6` component currently looks like:

```
export const DH6 = styled(H6)`
  color: ${(props) => (props.white ? "white" : null)};
  display: ${(props) => (props.flex ? "flex" : null)};
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.opaque ? 0.7 : null)};
  font-weight: ${(props) => (props.heavy ? 500 : 300)};
  text-align: ${(props) => (props.center ? "center" : null)};
  font-style: ${(props) => (props.italics ? "italic" : null)};
  text-decoration: ${(props) => (props.underline ? "underline" : null)};
`;
```

This works fine. I now want to apply the same props from `D1` to `D5`. Is there a way to do that in DRY fashion, rather than coping over the props? I tried assigning the props to a variable without success:

```
const generalProps = {
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.opaque ? 0.7 : null)},
  color: ${(props) => (props.white ? "white" : null)},
  display: ${(props) => (props.flex ? "flex" : null)},
  font-weight: ${(props) => (props.heavy ? 500 : 300)},
  text-align: ${(props) => (props.center ? "center" : null)},
  font-style: ${(props) => (props.italics ? "italic" : null)},
  text-decoration: ${(props) => (props.underline ? "underline" : null)}

}

export const DH6 = styled(H6)`
  {...generalProps}
`;
```

Is there any way to do prop assignment from variables in `styled-components`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an quick example you can use

```
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components'

const GlobalStyles = css`
  color: ${(props) => (props.white ? "white" : null)};
  display: ${(props) => (props.flex ? "flex" : null)};
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.opaque ? 0.7 : null)};
  font-weight: ${(props) => (props.heavy ? 500 : 300)};
  text-align: ${(props) => (props.center ? "center" : null)};
  font-style: ${(props) => (props.italics ? "italic" : null)};
  text-decoration: ${(props) => (props.underline ? "underline" : null)};
`

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
 ${GlobalStyles}
 // Other Styles
`
```

What you would do is to import `css` from the `styled-components`
with that you can generate the specific css and return it as a template literal [see the document](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css).
and for reusability you might usually use `${value}` that is equivalent for Spread Operator (or`{...value}`) for styled-components

Comment: I'm glad to help.